# Validation of Weird XML Structure

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd-validation

I have a mighty weird XML structure that I need to validate. At the same time I have to accept that I am not allowed to modify anything regarding its structure for political reasons.

I've managed to validate most of it by defining an idiotically overcomplex Schema. However a certain part of the XML seems almost impossible to validate with an XSD. Here is the problematic snippet:

```
<booktitles>
    <author>Some Author</author>
    <title>Title 1</title>
    <year>1666</year>
    <title>Title 2</title>
    <year>1919</year>
</booktitles>
```

So every **booktitles** entry contains exactly 1 **author** and a variable amount of **title** - **year** pairs.

So without modifying the XML structure (yes, I do realise how idiotic this sounds) is it possible to define an XSD which would validate/enforce it?

PS: I also have the possibility of using JaxB for the validation.

Comment: "it is not valid XML". Why? This looks valid to me. Mixing elements is legal.

Comment: @LutzHorn your are right. Removed my erroneous statement

Comment: There's nothing weird about it, nor anything invalid.  It's only poor XML style: repeating elements or groups should be put inside a "container" element.  And the WXS schema to validate it is as trivial as the DTD or RNG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="booktitles">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="author"/>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element ref="title"/>
          <xs:element ref="year"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="year" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Courtesy of [trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html), from this

```
<!ELEMENT   booktitles
            (author, (title, year)+)
            >

<!ELEMENT   author
            (#PCDATA)
            >

<!ELEMENT   title
            (#PCDATA)
            >

<!ELEMENT   year
            (#PCDATA)
            >
```